# Slick afterChange Event is not getting triggered on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

i want to fire my custom function on afterChange event of slick slider, i applied the following code, which is working in desktop, but not responding on mobile. In desktop, slick afterChange event triggers, while in mobile, afterChange event does not trigger and hence my custom function does not work.

```js
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
                
    $scope.slickIndex = currentSlide;
    $('.dots').find('#photobookdiv'+$scope.slickIndex).click();
    $scope.selectedLeft = $scope.slickIndex;
    

});



$scope.clickDot = function(index){
    $scope.slickIndex = index;
    $('.slick-dots').find('#slick-slide0'+index).click();
}
```

```html
<slick class="product-slider slider clearfix" ng-if="isData3Loaded" infinite=true slides-to-show=3 slides-to-scroll=1 dots=true autoplay=true responsive="breakpoints">

<div class="slick-item" id="photobook-div{{$index}}" ng-click="selectedProductByPreviewType($event,product.code,$index); activate(arrCategoryType); setClickedLeft($index)" ng-modal="product.categoryProduct" ng-repeat="product in arrCategoryType"  >
      
    
        <div class="for-link-content-page">
          <figure>
            <img ng-src="{{product.thumb_image}}" alt="{{product.alt}}" title="{{product.alt}}">
          </figure>
          <div>
            <strong>{{product.ProductCat}}<span>{{product.onlineText}}</span></strong>
            <small class="photobook-product-small-box"><b ng-if="$index != 2">{{'pb_hard_cover' | translate}} | {{'pb_soft_cover' | translate}}</b><b ng-if="false">{{'pb_soft_cover' | translate}}</b></small>
            <small>{{product.onlineDescription }}</small>
            <a  ng-href="/{{ product.categoryUrl }}"><span class="more-info-book">{{product.more_info}} </span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </slick>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <ul class="dots" style="display: block;position: relative;bottom: 0;" role="tablist">
      <li id="photobookdiv{{$index}}" ng-modal="product.categoryProduct" ng-repeat="product in arrCategoryType" ng-click="selectedProductByPreviewType($event,product.code,$index);  activate(arrCategoryType); setClickedLeft($index); clickDot($index)" ng-class="{'active':$index == selectedLeft}">
       
      </li>
    </ul>
```